# CxFreeze Python Compilation Error

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile my Python 3.4 script into an executable for easy redistribution. I chose to use cxfreeze as it is one of the few that supports Python 3. However, when running the command to compile the script, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\Desktop\DataMotion\Python\MailChecker.py", line 1, in <mo
dule>
    from tkinter import *
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_u
nlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_b
ackward_compatible
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'
```

But, I don't understand what's wrong other than it is complaining that _fix_up_module doesn't exist.

**UPDATE:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cxfreeze", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\main.py", line 187, in main
    silent = options.silent)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 130, in __init
__
    for n in self._GetDefaultBinPathExcludes() + binPathExcludes]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 270, in _GetDe
faultBinPathExcludes
    import cx_Freeze.util
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Many other Q/A's suggest using the 32 bit version of cxfreeze. But I did as I downloaded this one: cx_Freeze‑4.3.3.win32‑py3.4.exe

If I compile using cxfreeze 64 bit I get no errors. However, the resultant exe does not run.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/81/python-34-venv-importlib-attributeerror). You can download cx_Freeze from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) to get around it.

Comment: Thanks. I see it installed in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze. But how do I use it? Do I run the freeze script?

Comment: Once you've installed it, freeze your application the same way you were doing before, either with a setup.py script or with the cxfreeze command.

Comment: Would I have to uninstall the old cxfreeze that was installed or did it overwrite that one?

Comment: Ok I tried running the command again and now I am faced with a new error. See my updated question @ThomasK

Comment: It looks like you have 64-bit Python, so you need to install 64-bit cx_Freeze as well. It has to match your Python version. What goes wrong with the exe when you freeze it with 64-bit cx_Freeze?

Comment: It looks like it opens the command prompt and just closes. No error or anything. If I run the program from the command line I get no output or window.

Comment: Try putting print statements in your application startup code, then freeze it and run it from a command prompt to work out how far it's getting. It's weird that it gives no output at all.

Comment: @ThomasK, I have done what you asked and all prints do run but the tk gui does not. Aha! it wanted root.mainloop() at the end of the script. However, external libraries that were used seem to have not been compiled correctly as their functions now do not work.

Comment: Ah, were you running it in IDLE before? I think IDLE automatically makes Tkinter GUIs start (because it uses Tkinter itself). You should be able to write that up as an answer to your own question. It's probably best to open new questions for the other problems.

Comment: Ok that's true. I will write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of Thomas K's hard work and timely responses we finally figured out the problem. I did indeed need 64 bit version of cxfreeze that matched my python installation. To make the Tkinter gui work, it is needed to add

```
root.mainloop()
```

to the bottom of your python file if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 1):

This response pertains to Python 3.4 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

In my case, I had mixed 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python and cx_Freeze.  To fix, I completely uninstalled cx_Freeze and Python and reinstalled both, taking care to ensure that I downloaded and installed the proper 64-bit versions of each.

Prior to reinstalling, I had pywin32 installed as well.  I removed it but did not reinstall it.  I don't know if that had a hand in causing my issues or not (I have no need of it right now, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

to add to @DigitalSage answer (which is perfectly good!)

I found issues with Python 3.6 and the new version of cxFreeze

Download Python 3.6 **32 bit** and it should work fine  with the latest version of cxFreeze.

Also a good idea would be to look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) where you can have many different python environments on your machine that you can use. It saves you using the PATH Variable and possibly corrupting you installations.

Sometimes I have to use older versions of Python for backwards compatibility and it saves me a ton of headaches.